# Chroma Shader not working properly on IOS

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

**Update: this was fixed in Unity 5.3**

I wrote a Chroma Shader for Sprites. Its based on Unity's buildin shader *Sprites-Diffuse* Shader which you can download [here](http://unity3d.com/get-unity)

I added a texture to map the second color and a color property.

The shader works fine on Windows/Android devices. But on IOS the chromamap seems to has a offset.

I appreciate every hint.

---

The MainTexture (Actually a white circle on transparency ;))
[image: MainTexture]

---

The ChromaMap
[image: ChromaMap]

---

### Result

```
_Color  = Black

_ChromaColor = Orange
```

Android
[image: Result on Windows/Android]
IOS
[image: Result on IOS]

---

### The shader

```
Shader "Sprites/Chroma"
{
    Properties
    {
        [PerRendererData] _MainTex ("Sprite Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _ChromaTex ("Chroma Map", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Color ("Tint", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _ChromaColor ("ChromaColor", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        [MaterialToggle] PixelSnap ("Pixel snap", Float) = 0
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags
        { 
            "Queue"="Transparent" 
            "IgnoreProjector"="True" 
            "RenderType"="Transparent" 
            "PreviewType"="Plane"
            "CanUseSpriteAtlas"="True"
        }

        Cull Off
        Lighting Off
        ZWrite Off
        Blend One OneMinusSrcAlpha

        Pass
        {
        CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma multi_compile _ PIXELSNAP_ON
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata_t
            {
                float4 vertex   : POSITION;
                float4 color    : COLOR;
                float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 vertex   : SV_POSITION;
                fixed4 color    : COLOR;
                half2 texcoord  : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            fixed4 _Color;
            fixed4 _ChromaColor;

            v2f vert(appdata_t IN)
            {
                v2f OUT;
                OUT.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, IN.vertex);
                OUT.texcoord = IN.texcoord;
                OUT.color = IN.color * _Color;
                #ifdef PIXELSNAP_ON
                OUT.vertex = UnityPixelSnap (OUT.vertex);
                #endif

                return OUT;
            }

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            sampler2D _ChromaTex;
            sampler2D _AlphaTex;
            float _AlphaSplitEnabled;

            fixed4 SampleSpriteTexture (float2 uv)
            {
                fixed4 color = tex2D (_MainTex, uv);
                if (_AlphaSplitEnabled)
                    color.a = tex2D (_AlphaTex, uv).r;

                return color;
            }

            fixed4 frag(v2f IN) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 c = SampleSpriteTexture (IN.texcoord) * IN.color;
                fixed chroma = tex2D (_ChromaTex, (IN.texcoord)).a;
                c.rgb = lerp(c.rgb,_ChromaColor.rgb,chroma);
                c.rgb *= c.a;
                return c;
            }
        ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the project, I'd double check that the texture you use has the same import settings as it has for android. Things like compressing it can cause all sorts of problems.

Comment: have you tried the Y flipping?
#if UNITY_UV_STARTS_AT_TOP
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-PlatformDifferences.html

Comment: hey @MariusJunak - did you ever figure this?  It's good to clean out old questions.

Comment: Hey Joe, actually not, the bug seems to be fixed with Unity 5.3. i'm going to edit the question later today.

Comment: As a hot fix you could compensate the offset by counter-offsetting from C#. See here
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetTextureOffset.html

Comment: Your main texture should be power of 2 like your chroma map. Try same size textures.

Comment: Hey, the link you poster as `here` (to download the shade) is for the Unity Pro buy page